# React Native KeyboardAvoidingView with Expo

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIqxV.jpg)
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FonPj.jpg)

I've seen posts about this error on Github and StackOverFlow. I've tried almost all of them, but my problem is still not resolved.

`Register.js`

```
import React from "react";
import {
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  Keyboard,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
} from "react-native";
import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import styles from "../styles/RegisterStyle";

function Register({ navigation }) {
  const [passwordVisibility, setPasswordVisibility] = React.useState(false);

  const managePasswordVisibility = () => {
    setPasswordVisibility(!passwordVisibility);
  };


  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView style={{flex:1}}>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
        <View style={styles.inner}>
          <View style={styles.frame_1}>
            <Text style={styles.headerText}>Create an account</Text>
            <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", left: 24 }}>
              <Text style={styles.headerText2}>
                Enter your account details below or
              </Text>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Login")}>
                <Text style={styles.headerText3}> log in</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.frame_2}>
            <Text style={styles.frame_2_text}>Username</Text>
            <TextInput
              placeholder="Username"
              style={styles.frame_2_text_input}
            />
            <Text style={styles.frame_2_text}>Date of Birth</Text>
            <TextInput
              placeholder="MM / DD / YYYY"
              style={styles.frame_2_text_input}
            />
            <Text style={styles.frame_2_text}>Email</Text>
            <TextInput placeholder="Email" style={styles.frame_2_text_input} />
            <Text style={styles.frame_2_text}>Password</Text>
            <View>
              <TextInput
                placeholder="Password"
                style={styles.frame_2_text_input}
              />
              <TouchableOpacity
                activeOpacity={0.8}
                style={styles.visibiltyButton}
                onPress={() => managePasswordVisibility()}
              >
                {passwordVisibility ? (
                  <Ionicons name="eye-off-outline" size={24} color="black" />
                ) : (
                  <Ionicons name="eye-outline" size={24} color="black" />
                )}
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.frame_3}>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.frame_3_button}>
              <Text style={styles.frame_3_button_text}>Sign Up</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  );
}

export default Register;
```

`RegisterStyle.js`

```
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native";

const dark_gray = "#545F71";

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: "white",
      },
      inner: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'space-around',
      },
      headerText: {
        fontSize: 34,
        lineHeight: 36,
        letterSpacing: -0.64,
        fontStyle: "normal",
        fontWeight: "700",
        fontFamily: "Inter-Bold",
        color: dark_gray,
        left: 24,
      },
      headerText2: {
        fontSize: 18,
        fontFamily: "Inter-Regular",
        fontStyle: "normal",
        fontWeight: "400",
        letterSpacing: -0.32,
        lineHeight: 22,
        color: dark_gray,
      },
      headerText3: {
        fontSize: 18,
        fontFamily: "Inter-Semibold",
        fontStyle: "normal",
        fontWeight: "400",
        letterSpacing: -0.32,
        lineHeight: 22,
        fontWeight: "600",
        textDecorationLine: "underline",
      },
      frame_1: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent:'flex-end',
    },
      frame_2: {
        marginTop: 24,
        marginHorizontal: 24,
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        gap: 20,
        justifyContent: "flex-start",
        flex: 2,
      },
      frame_2_text: {
        fontSize: 14,
      },
      frame_2_text_input: {
        borderWidth: 1,
        height: 60,
        borderRadius: 10,
        padding:10,
      },
      frame_3: {
        marginTop: 24,
        marginHorizontal: 24,
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        gap: 20,
        justifyContent: "center",
        flex: 1,
      },
      frame_3_button: {
        backgroundColor: dark_gray,
        height: 60,
        borderRadius: 10,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
      },
      frame_3_button_text: {
        fontSize: 18,
        color: "white",
      },
      visibiltyButton: {
        position: 'absolute',
        right: 10,
        marginVertical: 17,
    },
      forgot_password: {
        fontSize: 14,
        color: "black",
        textAlign: "center",
        textDecorationLine: "underline",
        fontFamily: "Inter-Bold",
        fontWeight: "600",
      },
});

export default styles;
```

i tried behavior:padding,none,position and keyboardVerticalOffset but nothing changed

Btw i tried only on one phone
Android 13 / Google Experience
and i'm working with Expo

thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve your desired behavior In 2 ways ,

1. Is using the combination of scrollview and keyboardavoiding view which was provided by react native library,Example below,

```js
 <ScrollView
                ref={scrollViewRef}
                style={styles.container}
                contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
                keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"
            >
                <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.container} behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'position' : 'padding'} >
                // Rest 
                // Of Your 
                // Code
                </KeyboardAvoidingView>
            </ScrollView>
```

2. Is using 3rd party library KeyboardAwareScrollview. Install This using

```js
npm install react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view
                 or           
yarn add react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view
```

Import KeyboardAwareScrollView

```js
import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view";
```

Example Below

```js
  <KeyboardAwareScrollView
      style={{ flex: 1 }}
      resetScrollToCoords={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
      contentContainerStyle={styles.container} // Add this style to your container
      scrollEnabled={true}
    >
    
      <View style={styles.inner}>
        {/* Your existing content */}
      </View>
      
    </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
```